# Beginner TypeError: 'data' is an invalid keyword argument for Vocab

Tags: python

I wanted to start programming and thus looked at some tutorials on YouTube.
I have followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dam0GPOAvVI&t=1767s) 1:1 but it still doesn't work and I am stuck, can someone maybe help me fix this?

```py
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, request, flash
from flask_login import login_required, current_user
from .models import Vocab
from . import db

views = Blueprint('views', __name__)

@views.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        vocab = request.form['vocab']

        if len(vocab) < 1:
          flash('Vocabulary is too short!', category='error')
        else:
            # somehow can't find the problem, the vocab can't be saved in the database, data is apparently an invalid keyword
            new_vocab = Vocab(data=vocab, user_id=current_user.id)
            db.session.add(new_vocab)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('Vocabulary added successfully', category='success')

    return render_template("home.html", user=current_user)
```

models.py :

```py
from . import db
from flask_login import UserMixin
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

class Vocab(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = db.Column(db.String(10000))
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), default=func.now())
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(150), unique=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(150))
    password = db.Column(db.String(100))
    notes = db.relationship('Vocab')
```

Comment: Since the error appears to be in the Vocab class, it's hard to figure out a solution without seeing that class. The error is telling you that 'data' is not a keyword parameter in Vocab's __init__ method, have you checked there?

Comment: Why do you think `Vocab()` takes in a `data` parameter? Can you provide the timestamp in the video where you got that from? Or was it from somewhere else?

Comment: You should show us your `models.py`.  It's likely you don't have fields called `data` and `user_id` defined in your model.

Comment: @kcsquared u are right I wrote 'text' instead of 'data'. I changed that now but I still get a failure message that says: sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) table vocab has no column named data
[SQL: INSERT INTO vocab (data, date, user_id) VALUES (?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ?)]
[parameters: ('        hello', 1)]

Comment: @RandomDavis i am currently at this part https://youtu.be/dam0GPOAvVI?t=7361 2:02:41.

Comment: @TimRoberts I have added the model.py but I still get an error message sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) table vocab has no column named data
[SQL: INSERT INTO vocab (data, date, user_id) VALUES (?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ?)]
[parameters: ('        hello', 1)]

Comment: Did you recreate your tables?  The tutorial shows how to do that.  Just because you change your model, that doesn't change the database unless you delete the tables and tell sqlalchemy to recreate them.

Comment: @TimRoberts ahh oke I deleted the table. Trying to fix all errors I tried to change some things which led to even more errors. I probably will restart everything again. But thank you for your help!